# how to disable copy paste functionality to single line editor in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I need to disable copy/paste functionality for a single line editor in power builder.

I tried keyShift! and KeyControl! to null the clipboard data when the user is trying to paste. but didn't work it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Doesn't work is a bit unspecific, and it might also help to actually show the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the `Copy` functionality, define the Single-line edit as `Password`.
Of course, this will hide the content of that field, but it is most probably what you want to achieve, as I cannot imagine another reason to want to diable the 'copy' functionnality.

Similarly, to avoid the `Paste` possibility, define it as `Display only`.

You can also play programmatically with those options.